# ftp plugin for netbeans 7.1.1 mac

Tags: ftp, netbeans-7

I am trying to use my ftp server on netbeans. Is there a way to only put the host and username + password in and then just see all the folders that are on the server?

I already searched for this but I can't seem to find it anywhere.
I am using a mac and netBeans 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure that ant-commons-net.jar is copied to: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 6.7.1\java2\modules\ext

Then modify your project's build-impl.xml file, located under the nbproject directory.

Add a new task, such as this, using your ftpsite, username, and pass. Keep that file safe unless you modify it to prompt each time. To execute, run the ftp task by expanding the build.xml from the NB files tree tab.

Code:

```
                ==================== 
                    FTP SECTION 
                ==================== 

--> 
<target depends="jar" description="Build." name="ftp"> 
   <ftp server="FTPSITEURLHERE" userid="USERIDHERE" password="PASSWORDHERE"> 
    <fileset file="${dist.dir}/${application.title}.jar" /> 
  </ftp> 
</target> 
<!--
```

Comment: I am using a mac. so i that is much more different then what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean,  you want to create some project from FTP server and don't want to specify exact path? If so you can leave upload directory with just "/" and the same of "initial directory" and it should work

Comment: I don't think he wants to create a project, it seems he just want to connect with ftp

Comment: thanks but maarten is right i just want to connect with ftp and just see everything thats on there